# Onclick event not working IE8

Tags: javascript

I have tried the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RemoveFile('1');return false;" id="btnremove1">remove</a>
```

The onclick event works with Google Chrome and Firefix, but not in IE8. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: 'RemoveFile(this)' try this.

Comment: Better  try like this `onclick='RemoveFile("1");return false;' `  How supposed it should work? Already it has href?  Provide more info

Comment: What does it say in the developer tools in IE when you click on the link? Is there an error?

Comment: The `onclick` works also in IE. "Not working" doesn't describe your problem at all. Please tell what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 2):

In IE, `href` and `onclick` are set, and the `href` using `void(0)` will let the browser DO NOT EXECUTE the `onclick` action.

For your cases, I suggest you change the `href` to `href="javascript:;"` or `href="#"`.
And there is no change for your current `onclick`.

I have no idea why, but actually this is solution.

---

Remark:
Also you can merge `href` and `onclick` into `href`.
For your case: `href="javascript:RemoveFile('1');return false;"`

Comment: Did you test the claim in the first paragraph with a real IE8? IE10 and all emulations of IE8 fire `onclick` before handling `href`...

Comment: @Teemu, I found this problem in IE6, and I also get the same result in IE7. But in honest, I does NOT tried in IE 8, 9 and 10.